# How do I see how much savings I will have at the end of the budget period with GnuCash?

Tags: savings, budget, gnucash

I have set up a budget in GnuCash for a one year period, and I started out with some money in each of my accounts. How do I find out how much money I will be left with at the end of the budget period?

GnuCash allows me to add a "Totals" column in the budget, but it separately totals my Income and Expenses top-level accounts (including the sub-levels) but I can't seem to find a way for it to tell me "This is how much you have after deducting the total expenses from your total income, and also adding your starting amounts from your Asset accounts".

At the moment it seems quite annoying to track down the starting amounts for all my accounts and manually doing those calculations... I mean, that's what I'm using a software for...

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Is GnuCash also a forecasting tool (or are there forecasting reports you can run from inside GC)?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a forecasting tool in GnuCash. There is a Budget Report, which has the problems I mentioned in my post, and now I also found a "Budget Profit & Loss" report, which shows me a total revenue, total expenses and then a total net income (which is revenue minus expenses). But this too only takes into account the incomes but not the already existing amounts in my accounts.

Comment: Is this personal finance, or small business?